# How to make dynamic accordion content?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using this accordion control in WPF application : ayoutToolkit:Accordion.
I need to make dynamic content from database.
I tried like this:

```
private void RebuildView(Accordion accordion)
        {

            var scrollView = new ScrollViewer { VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto};
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                ShowGridLines = true,
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition(),
                    new ColumnDefinition(),
                }
            };
            int i = 0;
            foreach (AttributeModel item in ViewModel.Attributes)
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(60) };
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
                var label = new Label { Content = item.label, Foreground = Brushes.Black, FontSize = 20 };
                Grid.SetRow(label, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(label,0);
                grid.Children.Add(label);
                i++;
            }
            scrollView.Content = grid;
            accordion.ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(scrollView);
        }
```

but I'm not sure how to make it.

Comment: if your viewmodel has got a list of data, avoid doing it by code, that's not the right way...use an item control and data template with NO code. Think that, basically if you write c# in WPF to manipulate GUI then you are certainlly wrong...

Comment: Then I have livtview into accordionitem.

Comment: why not ? have a look to that http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/02/20/How-to-play-the-Accordion-WPF-Toolkit.aspx -

Comment: Then I have livtview into accordionitem.
Can I bind other variable in the listview?

[here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mystorage-ded50.appspot.com/o/test.txt?alt=media&token=1b758f89-0d65-4964-8b28-051575c1ce99)

Comment: yes, your code seems ok - you can use any list control = listbox, listview, itemcontrol...